# Php - about arrays and fetch

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Helow!
I'm implementing a compagination/paging in PHP.
I'm using a GET variable for the page number.

In the while, how can I "split" my mysqli query result into more small arrays with x rows each using $page to select the correct rows?

This is my code that shows all the results in one page.

```
$page = (int)$_GET['page'];
$query="SELECT * FROM videos WHERE video_categoria LIKE '%$q%'";
require 'db_connection.php';
$resultado = mysqli_query($dbc,$query); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    $video_num = (int)$row["video_numero"];                         
    include('video_box.inc');}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use LIMIT. There's not enough information in your question to provide an example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use: limit offset, rows.
Google that how to use  mysql limit